# Redirect after javascript alert

Tags: javascript, alert

I am working with asp.net and javascript. I am showing some javascript error message like

```
function validateRegistration() {
    alert('Error');
}
```

After the user presses OK from the alertbox, I want to redirect him to another page. If I write `Response.Redirect("myPage.aspx");` after calling the javascript function, the page is redirected without showing the alert box.

How can I do that?
Thanks

EDIT:

Actually I am using [SweetAlert](http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert) library. Is it possible to have the same result from this library?

Comment: `window.location.href = "myPage.aspx"`, not figuring that out shows no research effort

Answer (score 1):

You can take them to the new page with JavaScript:

```
function validateRegistration() {
    alert('Error');
    location.href = "myPage.aspx";
}
```

Since `alert` blocks until the user clicks OK, that will wait until they've dismissed the alert, and then switch to the new page.

Comment: @TanujWadhwa: check the documentation